# .net core not connecting to the changed database in appsettings.json connectionstrings in visual studio debug

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, connection-string

I am working on a .net core project, I wanted to change the connectionstring of the database in appsettings.json. 
I had created a duplicate database and named it originalname_fake01 and made a clone of the original database for testing.

I have also changed the database name in appsettings.developement.json. Everything seems fine but when I run the application in debug mode in visual studio. the data was being pulled from the original database rather than the changed database name in appsettings.json.

Here is my `appsettings` `connectionstrings` code:
    Old connectionstring was

```
"connectionStrings": {
"MyConnectionString": 
"Server=localhost;port=3306;database=mydb;user=root;password=rt123;"
}
```

changed connection string (new)

```
"connectionStrings": {
"FakeConnectionString": 
"Server=localhost;port=3306;database=mydb_fake01;user=root;password=rt123;"
}
```

I am not able to understand why it is connecting to the old database rather than the new database even after changing the `connectionstring`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you load the connection string and how do you connect to the database? Have you set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development`?

Comment: In .NET Core the settings files have no special meaning. The providers and file names used to load configuration are configured at runtime. The WebHost in older .NET Core versions and the Generic Host in 2.2 and later "just" set up some default providers, and use the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to detect whether they run on dev or production

Comment: I connect to the database using default dbcontext configured in startup.cs using services.addDbcontext<myContext>. the development environment is set to Developement in visual studio debugger settings of the project.

Comment: make sure you are reading this 'FakeConnectionString' in startup.cs.

Comment: How is your `appsettings.json` and `appsetting.developement.json`?Could you share more details?And how is your `Startup.cs`?You need to add dbcontext like below:`services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options =>           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("FakeConnectionString")));` And if you also add this:`services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options =>           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));`You need to put it after `FakeConnectionString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally able to find the problem in the dbcontext.cs modelbuilder. There is a code line which has strongly typed Schema Name.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
         OnModelCreatingImpl(modelBuilder);

         modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MyDB");
}
```

I changed it use the new schema as below:

```
modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MyDB_Fake01");
```

I don't understand why we need to give schema name in both connectionstring and in modelbuilder. I Guess we should avoid explicit schema name targeting in ModelBuilder so that, whenever the connectionstring is changed. it will target the database correctly.

Anyways, the problem is solved as the application is connecting to the intended database.

Comment: PS: Removing the **modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MyDB_Fake01");** has no effect. So it can be safely removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the development settings to override the production settings you need to use the *same* names and full path. Your connection string should be named `MyConnectionString`, not `MyConnectionString` if you want the DbContext to pick it automatically.

JSON setting files have no special meaning in .NET Core, they are just files. Every provider produces key/value pairs in the form `Section1:Subsection1:Attribute1, Value`. Newer provider values override earlier values. Providers can be JSON or XML file readers, *INI* file readers, databases etc. In all cases, the settings are flattened to path/value pairs.

The file

```
"connectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Server=localhost;port=3306;database=mydb;user=root;password=rt123;"
}
```

Produces a value named `connectionStrings:MyConnectionString` whose value is `Server=localhost;port=3306;database=mydb;user=root;password=rt123;`. To override this you need to specify a setting with the *same* path.

The default Host builder specifies [some default settings providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0#default-builder-settings). From the docs, those are :

> - appsettings.json.
> - appsettings.{Environment}.json.
>     = Secret Manager when the app runs in the Development environment.
> - Environment variables.
> - Command-line arguments.

Settings specified lower down the list override previous ones. This means that on a development machine, the `connectionStrings:MyConnectionString` in `appsettings.Developoment.json` overrides the element with the same name in `appsettings.json`.

This also means that we can override the connection string with an environment variabl or a command-line argument, eg

```
dotnet run /connectionStrings:MyConnectionString Server=localhost;port=3306;database=mydb;user=root;password=rt123;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a file named "secrets.json" which overrides all other appSettings configuration. Make sure it has correct Database name.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. In your changed connection string (new) setting, change the `FakeConnectionString` to `MyConnectionString`. If you have same keys in `appsettings.json` and in `appsettings.development.json` then latter will override the former.

```
"connectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Server=localhost;port=3306;database=mydb_fake01;user=root;password=rt123;"
}
```

> P.S. This is applicable to any environment not only to development

Answer (score 0):

The file named "secrets.json" worked for me as the default connection string was hardcoded there pointing to the old database.  Editing the connection string (Initial Catalog=dbName) to point to the current database name fixed the problem. Thanks!

sample content of "secrets.jason":
{
"ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection": "Data Source=TestSource;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
}