# How can I publish my web app with new connection strings?

Tags: sql-server, iis, connection-string, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using net core 3.1 with a Visual Basic Project and publishing to a folder that IIS uses for the website. We have recently moved our SQL database to a new server and I can't update the connection strings to connect to the new server.

When I change the connection strings in appsettings.json and directly through the connection services (See below) it doesn't change them for the web app (i.e. when I publish the application) it still uses the old connection strings.

I have a feeling the connection strings are stored on the web app server but can't seem to find where this might be, does anyone have any ideas?

[Visual Basic Connected Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7IWo.png)
[Appsettings Connection Strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kqsX.jpg)

I've tried changing the developmental/production/release versions of appsettings to no luck. I've had a look through some questions already posed on here and they are talking about the web.config file but this is generated when I publish the application, I have tried changing this manually to add the connection strings but this hasn't worked.

EDIT: So apparently the connection strings were saved in the environment variables, I changed them and still no luck. I tried recycling the application pool and restarting/rebuilding the web app and still not working.

Comment: Have you tried to recycle pools from iis? Also see something like       ChangeToken.OnChange(() => configurationRoot.GetReloadToken(), () =>
            {
               
            });

Comment: @kostasch. i've just recycled them and no luck, thanks

Comment: https://www.dundas.com/support/learning/documentation/administration-configuration-customization/how-to/how-to-recycle-the-application-pool

Comment: @kostasch. sorry, could you clarify what you mean by ChangeToken.OnChange(() => configurationRoot.GetReloadToken(), () => { })?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/change-tokens?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Can we assume that you've scanned your codebase and confirmed that all usages of `New SqlConnection` are in fact only using the connection strings from appsettings.json and not hardcoding them - or using `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to modify them on-the-fly?

Comment: There was a similar discussion here that may provide provide you with some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58817627/net-core-not-connecting-to-the-changed-database-in-appsettings-json-connections Not sure if it will help.

Comment: Thanks all for help, it turned out the ConnectionStrings were added to environment variables and I didn't realize.